# Ruby on Rails is changing id param in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have problem with rails form - it's adding another id param in the edit form.
I've already tried to add the hidden tag with object id.

sever log

```
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:49:in `update'
Started PATCH "/products/index" for 213.17.150.6 at 2018-06-19 19:21:10 +0000
Cannot render console from 213.17.150.6! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ProductsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "/products/18/edit"=>{"id"=>"18", "name"=>"test", "price"=>"3.0", "category_id"=>"55"}, "authenticity_token"=>"DMzH7e8ExK6kvciAWyvAb73Rsj84Py8RIufbP+jxxGmH/n5ITC+XGOqdG2LTw3J7XDTRbOsoAUIXXxLwNkDtKg==", "commit"=>"Edit", "id"=>"index"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=index):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:49:in `update'
```

and here is edit form

```
<% @categories = Category.all %>
<%= form_for edit_product_path(product), method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: product.id %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, value: product.name, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.number_field :price, value: product.price, step: 0.01, class: "form-control" %>

  <% if Category.any? %>          
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <%= f.select :category_id do %>
      <% if product.category_id == nil %>
        <%= content_tag(:option, "Uncategorized", value: nil, :disabled => true, selected:"selected") %>
      <% end %>
      <% @categories.each do |o| %>
        <%= content_tag(:option, o.name, value: o.id) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :image %>
  <%= image_tag product.image.url(:edit) if product.image? %>
  <%= f.file_field :image, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg', class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>

  <%= f.submit "Edit", class: "btn btn-light" %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#product_image').bind('change', function() {
      var size_in_mb = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
      if (size_in_mb > 5)
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose smaller file')
    })
  </script>

<% end %>
```

My edit form is on the index page (I want to edit products from index page)

Comment: You mean `"id"=>"index"`? it's taking the id from the url. Where it should be `categories/:id/edit` it is `categories/index`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)** helper is built like that: `form_for(record, options = {}, &block)`
You need to specify first the record then you can pass an url as option.

If you defined your routes as CRUD, `edit_product_path` is a GET request and you shouldn't use it for update action.

So you can fix your form like:

```ruby
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% @categories = Category.all %> #btw, you can define this instance variable inside your controller products#index
  <%= form_for product, url: product_path(product), remote: true do |f| %>

    #the form

  <%= f.submit "Edit", class: "btn btn-light" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You shouldn't need hidden field this way anymore.